# MySQL dump on WAMP server using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to dump the mysql database using a PHP file.
I am using windows 7 OS.

but I am always getting error;
This is my code

```
$user='root';
$pass='mypassword';
$host='localhost';
//$sql_file='db_backup.sql';
$cmd = "e:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.12\\bin\\mysqldump -h$host  -u$user -p$pass hospitalerp > db_backup.sql";
exec($cmd, $output, $return);
if ($return != 0) { //0 is ok
    die('Error: ' . implode("\r\n", $output));
}

echo "dump complete";
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of error? Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your file to see any possible error and show us.

Comment: I have added the line as suggest by you, but I am still getting only the `Error:` is showing on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, may someone find it useful.

```
$user='root';
$pass='mypassword';
$host='localhost';

$cmd='e:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump --user='.$user.' --password='.$pass .' --host=localhost hospitalerp > db_backup4.sql';
//var_dump($cmd);exit;
exec($cmd, $output, $return);
if ($return != 0) { //0 is ok
    die('Error: ' . implode("\r\n", $output));
}

echo "dump complete";
```

Comment: It appears the change was in `$cmd`, where you switched from double quotes and escaped backslashes to single quotes and non-escaped backslashes.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

I note that mysqldump need the exe extension, just like:

```
$cmd='e:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump.exe --user='.$user.' --password='.$pass .' --host=localhost hospitalerp > db_backup4.sql';
```

I tried this on a Windows 10 PC